# Can I write/read Google Cloud Storage from my website which is not a Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Can I write (and read) files using PHP in my google cloud storage when Im not using a Google App Engine?

In other words, may I have my website running on another web hosting and use google cloud to store (and read in future) my JSON files only? the JSON files need to be written on runtime and by users.

Answer (score 1):

you can store any files using any programming language like PHP to any cloud storage like google cloud storage or amazon s3, dropbox...etc

Checkout this documentation:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-storage-ga